# Dynamic Class change working intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a page where it verifies the number of bowlers on a team against how many are supposed to be on the team.   If there are too many bowlers on the team, it will prompt an alert.   I have the same script for the visitor team and the home team, but it is only working properly on the home team.

```
/* Clear Visitor Table (except header row) */
jQuery('#table_visitor tr').not(function(){ 
   return!!jQuery(this).has('th').length; }).remove();
if(vis.length<=bowlers_team) {
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").empty();
    /* Populate the table */
    var table="table_visitor";
    for(var i=0; i<vis.length; i++) {
        jQuery("#"+table).append('<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+vis[i]['Name']+'</td><td>'+parseInt(vis[i]['curr_avg'])+'</td><td>'+vis[i]['curr_handi']+'</td></td>');
    }
} else {
console.log("Too many bowlers on Visistors.\r\n");
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").append("<span>Teams cannot exceed "+bowlers_team+" bowlers per team.</span>");
}
```

Then the same exists for the home team:

```
/* Clear Home Table (except header row) */
jQuery('#table_home tr').not(function(){ return 
   !!jQuery(this).has('th').length; }).remove();
if(home.length<=bowlers_team) {
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").empty();
    /* Populate the table */
    var table="table_home";
    for(var i=0; i<home.length; i++) {
        jQuery("#"+table).append('<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+home[i]['Name']+'</td><td>'+parseInt(home[i]['curr_avg'])+'</td><td>'+home[i]['curr_handi']+'</td></td>');
    }
} else {
console.log("Too many bowlers on HOme.\r\n");
    jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
    jQuery("#alert_window").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
    jQuery("#alert_window").append("<span>Teams cannot exceed "+bowlers_team+" bowlers per team.</span>");
}
```

I'm at a loss to why this works properly for the home team but not the visitor team.   I've set this up for viewing at https://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/scoresheet-generator.   You can select the only league, then '2017 Fall' as the season.   Week # 5 and any match up.   Then drag a sub to the home to see how it should work.  Then drag that same person back to sub.   Next try to drag someone from sub to visitor and you'll note it does not work.  The alert window does not display (however, the error shows in the console log so I know it's getting to that portion of the function).

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Technical issue here on my end.

Both pieces of code WERE actually working.  The problem was that when an alert was created in the visitor portion of the code (adding the class [alert alert-danger] and appropriate span with the error message).   It was being cleared by the

```
jQuery("#alert_window").removeClass();
jQuery("#alert_window").find('span').remove();
```

lines in the home check.

Thus, I simply created a variable that stored whether or not there was an error.  Then as a last check, I would populate (or clear) the alerts.